# How to prevent users like the comment multiple times like "facebook or youtube like/dislike systems"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, express, comments

I am using express,react and mysql. I want to create like/dislike system for the comments. I googled it and most people recommended to disable the button after single click. But I don't want that. Even the user refreshes the tab or access his profile from another device. When he sees that comment again, he should see that he already liked that comment and he should not be able to like it again. I am thinking of storing all the likes and dislikes in the mysql database for each user. Does it decreases the number of queries to database and affect the performance? What is the proper solution?

Comment: The proper solution is indeed to write down somewhere that they already "liked". Otherwise how are you going to be able to stop them from liking again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the users who  liked/disliked a post (or a comment), you will have to insert a new row along with the `user-id` for each like/dislike. And regarding the multiple-likes problem, you will have to check whether or not there is a row with the same `user-id` and `comment-id`s as the ones you are getting from the `post` request, if so, just ignore the request and tell the user something like "cannot like more than once", otherwise insert a new row.

Another thing to consider is, what do you plan to do in cases where a user likes a comment and immediately unlikes it ? If you are sending real-time notifications, then the target will get a false notification (that is, if you don't tackle this problem). That was something I hadn't considered and there simply was no way (but i am sure there is a trick).

Comment: I am using socket.io for real time comment. I think I have to use it for like and dislike as well by creating specific events for them. In this case it will be faster I think. For immidiate  clicks, i will handle on the client side so user doesn't notice anything when they like or dislike.

Comment: @MukhammadAli By "i will handle on the client-side", are you saying that you will only send a like to the server-side if the user does not unlike after a certain number of seconds ?